# Live Agent PreChat API for external website

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

I have to use Prechat API of Live Agent to gather information about the customer.
I have successfully implemented this for force.com site but stuck on what values to set in the fields for external website?

Do I need to add VF pages for Prechat and PostChat for external website ?

1) Site for Resources
2) Pre-Chat Form Page
3) Pre-Chat Form URL
4) Post-Chat Page
5) Post-Chat URL

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Site for Resources must be your force.com site, this will be the proxy to serve your chat pages to the public.

2 and 3. Pre-chat form page, if your pre-chat form is a VF page, select it here, otherwise, enter the URL to your pre-chat page in your external site in the field below (Pre-Chat URL).

4 and 5. The same applies here, if you have a post-chat page (this is not required) created in visualforce, select this field, if this is an external page use the URL options instead.

Comment: Thanks @pepefloyd, As I am using live agent on a external website (not a force.com site) Do I still need to put force.com site in 1 (I don't have any force.com site created)

Comment: @NickSFDC If you won't be serving any VF pages, you don't need to use that.